# Error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps.

Tags: ios, watchkit

Verify that the value of WKWatchKitApp in your WatchKit App's Info.plist is set to YES.

Comment: Try solution from issues posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45930611/454896)

Answer (score 17):

After weeks and weeks of investigations i finally found out the problem.

The product name of the Iphone App was the same as the product name of the Watch App.

Once i changed the Product Name of the WatchApp it worked.

go to your targets. Select the watch app target
go to build settings. Search for Product Name
Edit your Product name to be different than the App Target!
Clean and Build. Should Work. Thanks

Comment: After changing the Product Name and building I was able to change it back and the error did not return.

Comment: The problem is that for AppStore the app and the Watch App *must* have the same name, so this is not the solution.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like this is the default error msg for random stuff on Xcode 7.

All of a sudden I got that error constantly when trying to Archive.
After retracing my steps I've learned that changing the `Build Location` to **Custom - > Relative to WorkSpace** is responsible for that error: `WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps..`

Setting the `Build Location` back to **Shared Folder -> Build** fixed it completely.

[image]